# Can't set some facebook permissions on first login

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

I'm making an app which will be integrated with facebook. I have to have access to user's friends_requests so I have to ask for "read_requests" permissions, and now it's complicated, I have been trying to do it both ways :
1) using LoginButton

```
LoginButton button = new LoginButton(this);
button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("read_requests"));
```

2) using Session:

```
Session.OpenRequest openrequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
openrequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("friend_requests"));
openrequest.setCallback(statusCallback);
session.openForRead(openrequest);
```

Both ways I can login to an app but it doesn't ask for extra permissions. I noticed that when I tried to get email permissions ("email" instead of "read_requests") it works fine. I know, I can get this extra permissions by using this:

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest request = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(Nowa.this, Arrays.asList("friend_requests"));
session.requestNewReadPermissions(request);
```

But I want to have access to friend_requests from the beginning, is there any way to do that ? Thanks for help

Comment: "read_requests" is an extended permission.
Did you specified in the app permission section that you will request for it?

Comment: I do it now (about 20 minutes ago) and it's still not working, I checked about 5 times ;)

Comment: Reading the Facebook SDK for Android. I found this 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.NewPermissionsRequest

There is a method setCallback. Why do you not try this and see what is coming back from your permission request.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but it's a method connected with "NewPermissionRequest" - I don't want to use NewPermissionRequest because it won't give me permission I need from the beginning

Comment: I think I found a solution, When I wanted to Login to my app, I always was cancelling the first dialog with "Install" option, when it's the second one which shows the permissions I want to have, my bad, sorry for inconvenience and thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it using (2) and it works OK: the dialog shows up as "TestApp would like to  access your public profile and requests". For all read permissions you should only see one dialog on Android, even if it's an extended permission. So if you are getting something different you should make sure you did not grant this permission already - if you did, you can remove it from your facebook account settings and try to login again.

Comment: I think I found a solution, When I wanted to Login to my app, I always was cancelling the first dialog with "Install" option, when it's the second one which shows the permissions I want to have, my bad, sorry for inconvenience and thanks for help ;)